# Python format count() method

Tags: python, count

I have created an application that helps crack coded words for school work. I had to use the `.count()` method to count how many times a letter occurs in a list of words. This is the output:

```
Counter({'\n': 9, '#': 8, '&': 7, '3': 6, '*': 4, '%': 4, '1': 3, '8': 3, '0': 3, ')': 2, '+': 2, '4': 2, '7': 2, '2': 2, '-': 2, '/': 1, ',': 1, '$': 1, '6': 1, '5': 1, '!': 1, '.': 1, ':': 1, '"': 1, "'": 1, '9': 1})
```

Is there a way I could format this to look better and be much more understandable?

Comment: you can use pretty printer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: First seems that you have used `collections.Counter` , second can you explain what you mean by *look better and be much more understandable* , can you give an example?

Comment: The user of the application needs to be able to pretty much understand watch is being shown so maybe something like this:

Comment: Maybe something like (A: 12, B: 3, C: 4) etc. and only show like 4 on a row if that makes sense. So a user could understand what it means instead of it being a huge list on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for keys, values in YourDictionaryHere.items():
    print keys, values
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks, don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
from collections import Counter

stuff = Counter({'\n': 9, '#': 8, '&': 7, '3': 6, '*': 4, '%': 4, '1': 3, '8': 3, '0': 3, ')': 2, '+': 2, '4': 2, '7': 2, '2': 2, '-': 2, '/': 1, ',': 1, '$': 1, '6': 1, '5': 1, '!': 1, '.': 1, ':': 1, '"': 1, "'": 1, '9': 1})

stuff = dict(stuff)
line = []
for i,kv in enumerate(stuff.iteritems(), start=1):
    line.append("%s : %d" % kv)
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print line
        line = []

if line: print line
```

Produces:

```
['\n : 9', '! : 1', '# : 8', '" : 1']
['% : 4', '$ : 1', "' : 1", '& : 7']
[') : 2', '+ : 2', '* : 4', '- : 2']
[', : 1', '/ : 1', '. : 1', '1 : 3']
['0 : 3', '3 : 6', '2 : 2', '5 : 1']
['4 : 2', '7 : 2', '6 : 1', '9 : 1']
['8 : 3', ': : 1']
```

To get more entries per line, change the `i % 4` line.